# How to hide blinking cursor in the EditText while making a screenshot

Tags: android, android-edittext, cursor

What I have: viewpager with EditText (with blinking cursor) at each Fragment. User inputs some text, after that app makes a screenshot, which going to storage.

The problem is that cursor appears at the screenshot and it's not beautiful

What I want: to hide cursor before making a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Can you programmatically disable the cursor for a moment prior to the screenshot?

```
setCursorVisible(false)
```

Comment: it doesn't help, a cursor will be invisible for all the time after 2nd fragment

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be checking if combination of keys is pressed. First case, You check if user pressed Volume Down+Power. When this occur, You set focus on any view which has not input for text. And after release recover focus on view with cursor. As I said (Volume Down+Power is probably one of few combination keys to take screenshot).

What is more, I do not know anything about Your screenshot-ing. Is it programmatically or made by user. My case was assuming screenshot is made by User. However for programmatically action it should also be working fine. There are plenty samples to handle if any key was pressed. It should be easy to achieve it.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what you application is using, for a web application include a css rule for the cursor like this.

```
<style type="text/css">
.nocursor { cursor:none; }
</style>
```